# how to use taskset -c option when hyperthreading/logical CPU is enabled

Tags: linux, pthreads, taskset

hyperthreading/logical CPU is enabled and lscpu shows 128 logical CPUs (there are 64 physical CPUs)

```
  NUMA node(s):         2
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):    0-31,64-95
  NUMA node1 CPU(s):    32-63,96-127
```

I am guessing that logical CPU #0-1 corresponds to physical CPU #0. logical CPU #2-3 corresponds to physical CPU #1.

If I want to use 'taskset -cp 1 thread_pid1' to bind thread_pid1 to physical CPU#1, which one of the following is the proper syntax?

```
taskset -cp 1 thread_pid1
taskset -cp 2,3 thread_pid1
taskset -cp 2 thread_pid1
```

Thanks.